# Elasticsearch Received plaintext traffic on an encrypted channel, closing connection Netty4TcpChannel

Tags: elasticsearch

I have just downloaded elasticsearch and run the elasticsearch.bat.
So i didn't modify anything, but when i try to access localhost:9200 or 9300 is not working.

Accordign to logs it started ok.

```
[2022-03-14T16:42:47,633][INFO ][o.e.i.r.RecoverySettings ] [DESKTOP-3DPA0JQ] using rate limit [40mb] with [default=40mb, read=0b, write=0b, max=0b]
[2022-03-14T16:42:47,664][INFO ][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule    ] [DESKTOP-3DPA0JQ] using discovery type [multi-node] and seed hosts providers [settings]
[2022-03-14T16:42:48,507][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [DESKTOP-3DPA0JQ] initialized
[2022-03-14T16:42:48,508][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [DESKTOP-3DPA0JQ] starting ...
[2022-03-14T16:42:48,564][INFO ][o.e.x.s.c.f.PersistentCache] [DESKTOP-3DPA0JQ] persistent cache index loaded
[2022-03-14T16:42:48,565][INFO ][o.e.x.d.l.DeprecationIndexingComponent] [DESKTOP-3DPA0JQ] deprecation component started
[2022-03-14T16:42:48,692][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [DESKTOP-3DPA0JQ] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9300}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9300}, {[::1]:9300}
[2022-03-14T16:42:49,065][INFO ][o.e.c.c.Coordinator      ] [DESKTOP-3DPA0JQ] cluster UUID [M7j_3np8QtCiMDZ8hLGu6w]
[2022-03-14T16:42:49,157][INFO ][o.e.c.s.MasterService    ] [DESKTOP-3DPA0JQ] elected-as-master ([1] nodes joined)[{DESKTOP-3DPA0JQ}{n3yQhC4cQveWn_x7QrQPYQ}{QSgY7a2zQDWZClJOW_2yEg}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}{cdfhilmrstw} completing election, _BECOME_MASTER_TASK_, _FINISH_ELECTION_], term: 10, version: 142, delta: master node changed {previous [], current [{DESKTOP-3DPA0JQ}{n3yQhC4cQveWn_x7QrQPYQ}{QSgY7a2zQDWZClJOW_2yEg}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}{cdfhilmrstw}]}
[2022-03-14T16:42:49,269][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterApplierService] [DESKTOP-3DPA0JQ] master node changed {previous [], current [{DESKTOP-3DPA0JQ}{n3yQhC4cQveWn_x7QrQPYQ}{QSgY7a2zQDWZClJOW_2yEg}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}{cdfhilmrstw}]}, term: 10, version: 142, reason: Publication{term=10, version=142}
[2022-03-14T16:42:49,326][INFO ][o.e.h.AbstractHttpServerTransport] [DESKTOP-3DPA0JQ] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9200}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9200}, {[::1]:9200}
[2022-03-14T16:42:49,327][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [DESKTOP-3DPA0JQ] started
[2022-03-14T16:42:49,379][INFO ][o.e.l.LicenseService     ] [DESKTOP-3DPA0JQ] license [f997c03d-7240-4ecf-be38-65f043eea771] mode [basic] - valid
[2022-03-14T16:42:49,380][INFO ][o.e.x.s.a.Realms         ] [DESKTOP-3DPA0JQ] license mode is [basic], currently licensed security realms are [reserved/reserved,file/default_file,native/default_native]
[2022-03-14T16:42:49,386][INFO ][o.e.g.GatewayService     ] [DESKTOP-3DPA0JQ] recovered [2] indices into cluster_state
[2022-03-14T16:42:49,880][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService] [DESKTOP-3DPA0JQ] current.health="GREEN" message="Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [GREEN] (reason: [shards started [[.geoip_databases][0], [.security-7][0]]])." previous.health="RED" reason="shards started [[.geoip_databases][0], [.security-7][0]]"
[2022-03-14T16:42:50,142][INFO ][o.e.i.g.DatabaseNodeService] [DESKTOP-3DPA0JQ] successfully loaded geoip database file [GeoLite2-Country.mmdb]
[2022-03-14T16:42:50,155][INFO ][o.e.i.g.DatabaseNodeService] [DESKTOP-3DPA0JQ] successfully loaded geoip database file [GeoLite2-ASN.mmdb]
[2022-03-14T16:42:51,002][INFO ][o.e.i.g.DatabaseNodeService] [DESKTOP-3DPA0JQ] successfully loaded geoip database file [GeoLite2-City.mmdb]
[2022-03-14T16:42:54,067][WARN ][o.e.x.s.t.n.SecurityNetty4HttpServerTransport] [DESKTOP-3DPA0JQ] received plaintext http traffic on an https channel, closing connection Netty4HttpChannel{localAddress=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:9200, remoteAddress=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:64318}
[2022-03-14T16:42:54,067][WARN ][o.e.x.s.t.n.SecurityNetty4HttpServerTransport] [DESKTOP-3DPA0JQ] received plaintext http traffic on an https channel, closing connection Netty4HttpChannel{localAddress=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:9200, remoteAddress=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:64319}
[2022-03-14T16:42:54,068][WARN ][o.e.x.s.t.n.SecurityNetty4HttpServerTransport] [DESKTOP-3DPA0JQ] received plaintext http traffic on an https channel, closing connection Netty4HttpChannel{localAddress=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:9200, remoteAddress=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:64320}
[2022-03-14T16:42:55,104][WARN ][o.e.x.s.t.n.SecurityNetty4HttpServerTransport] [DESKTOP-3DPA0JQ] received plaintext http traffic on an https channel, closing connection Netty4HttpChannel{localAddress=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:9200, remoteAddress=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:64321}
```

Comment: In the latest version (ES8), security is on by default (i.e. SSL/TLS). How do you try to access ES?

Comment: Directly on browser on http://localhost:9200/

Comment: Ok, just try `https://localhost:9200` instead

Comment: @Val I got this message (This page isn’t working) when I used http://localhost:9200. When I used https://localhost:9200, I got this message (Your connection is not private )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the latest version (ES8), security is on by default (i.e. SSL/TLS).

If you're accessing from the browser, just use `https` instead of `http`:

```
https://localhost:9200
    ^
    |
 add this
```

Answer (score 4):

Edit elasticsearch\config\elasticsearch.yml

```yaml
xpack.security.enabled: false

xpack.security.enrollment.enabled: false

pack.security.http.ssl:
  enabled: false
  keystore.path: certs/http.p12

xpack.security.transport.ssl:
  enabled: false
  verification_mode: certificate
  keystore.path: certs/transport.p12
  truststore.path: certs/transport.p12
```

Answer (score 0):

Lol, this is not solve :)))

```
xpack.security.enabled: false

xpack.security.enrollment.enabled: false

pack.security.http.ssl:
  enabled: false
  keystore.path: certs/http.p12

xpack.security.transport.ssl:
  enabled: false
  verification_mode: certificate
  keystore.path: certs/transport.p12
  truststore.path: certs/transport.p12
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The commenter is right, they are clear and you are not understanding... this is not a solution, it's just some text. And for someone who can parse it, it is garbage text for this problem. I wouldn't criticize this commenter for mentioning that this is not a solution... it's really not a solution at all.