# Getting Exceptions while running a Spring boot app with elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I was following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IiZZAu2Qtp0&ab_channel=LiliumCode

and the only changes I made were that I was using maven with eclipse instead. The rest of the code is exactly the same. When I run the app I get:

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'personController' defined in file [D:\Java Programs\Spring\elasticsearch\target\classes\com\elastic\elasticsearch\controller\PersonController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'personService' defined in file [D:\Java Programs\Spring\elasticsearch\target\classes\com\elastic\elasticsearch\service\PersonService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personRepository' defined in com.elastic.elasticsearch.repository.PersonRepository defined in @EnableElasticsearchRepositories declared on Config: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.UncategorizedElasticsearchException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Connection is closed; nested exception is ElasticsearchException[java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Connection is closed]; nested: ExecutionException[org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Connection is closed]; nested: ConnectionClosedException[Connection is closed];
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at com.elastic.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchApplication.main(ElasticsearchApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'personService' defined in file [D:\Java Programs\Spring\elasticsearch\target\classes\com\elastic\elasticsearch\service\PersonService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personRepository' defined in com.elastic.elasticsearch.repository.PersonRepository defined in @EnableElasticsearchRepositories declared on Config: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.UncategorizedElasticsearchException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Connection is closed; nested exception is ElasticsearchException[java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Connection is closed]; nested: ExecutionException[org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Connection is closed]; nested: ConnectionClosedException[Connection is closed];
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personRepository' defined in com.elastic.elasticsearch.repository.PersonRepository defined in @EnableElasticsearchRepositories declared on Config: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.UncategorizedElasticsearchException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Connection is closed; nested exception is ElasticsearchException[java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Connection is closed]; nested: ExecutionException[org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Connection is closed]; nested: ConnectionClosedException[Connection is closed];
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.UncategorizedElasticsearchException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Connection is closed; nested exception is ElasticsearchException[java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Connection is closed]; nested: ExecutionException[org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Connection is closed]; nested: ConnectionClosedException[Connection is closed];
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:224) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.lambda$instantiateClass$5(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:578) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.instantiateClass(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:578) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepositoryViaReflection(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:543) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.java:74) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:324) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:322) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:230) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:328) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.java:69) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.UncategorizedElasticsearchException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Connection is closed; nested exception is ElasticsearchException[java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Connection is closed]; nested: ExecutionException[org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Connection is closed]; nested: ConnectionClosedException[Connection is closed];
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.java:72) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.translateException(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:427) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.execute(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:410) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.RestIndexTemplate.doExists(RestIndexTemplate.java:103) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.AbstractIndexTemplate.exists(AbstractIndexTemplate.java:134) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository.<init>(SimpleElasticsearchRepository.java:92) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:211) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    ... 57 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Connection is closed
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performClientRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2078) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.15.2.jar:7.15.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1732) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.15.2.jar:7.15.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1717) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.15.2.jar:7.15.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.exists(IndicesClient.java:963) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.15.2.jar:7.15.2]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.RestIndexTemplate.lambda$doExists$2(RestIndexTemplate.java:103) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.execute(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:408) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
    ... 66 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Connection is closed
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.BaseFuture$Sync.getValue(BaseFuture.java:262) ~[elasticsearch-7.15.2.jar:7.15.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.BaseFuture$Sync.get(BaseFuture.java:249) ~[elasticsearch-7.15.2.jar:7.15.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.BaseFuture.get(BaseFuture.java:76) ~[elasticsearch-7.15.2.jar:7.15.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performClientRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2075) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.15.2.jar:7.15.2]
    ... 71 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Connection is closed
    at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.endOfInput(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:356) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.15.jar:4.4.15]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpClientConnection.consumeInput(DefaultNHttpClientConnection.java:261) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.15.jar:4.4.15]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:87) ~[httpasyncclient-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:40) ~[httpasyncclient-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:114) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.15.jar:4.4.15]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.15.jar:4.4.15]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.15.jar:4.4.15]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.15.jar:4.4.15]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.15.jar:4.4.15]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.15.jar:4.4.15]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:591) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.15.jar:4.4.15]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

My elasticsearch.yml:

```
# ======================== Elasticsearch Configuration =========================
#
# NOTE: Elasticsearch comes with reasonable defaults for most settings.
#       Before you set out to tweak and tune the configuration, make sure you
#       understand what are you trying to accomplish and the consequences.
#
# The primary way of configuring a node is via this file. This template lists
# the most important settings you may want to configure for a production cluster.
#
# Please consult the documentation for further information on configuration options:
# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/index.html
#
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
cluster.name: elastic_course
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
node.name: crud_node
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
#node.attr.rack: r1
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
#path.data: /path/to/data
#
# Path to log files:
#
#path.logs: /path/to/logs
#
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
#
# Lock the memory on startup:
#
#bootstrap.memory_lock: true
#
# Make sure that the heap size is set to about half the memory available
# on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this
# limit.
#
# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# By default Elasticsearch is only accessible on localhost. Set a different
# address here to expose this node on the network:
#
#network.host: 192.168.0.1
#
# By default Elasticsearch listens for HTTP traffic on the first free port it
# finds starting at 9200. Set a specific HTTP port here:
#
#http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, consult the network module documentation.
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when this node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
#discovery.seed_hosts: ["host1"]
#
#discovery.type: single-node
#
# Bootstrap the cluster using an initial set of master-eligible nodes:
#
#cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1"]
#
# For more information, consult the discovery and cluster formation module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
#
# Allow wildcard deletion of indices:
#
#action.destructive_requires_name: false

#----------------------- BEGIN SECURITY AUTO CONFIGURATION -----------------------
#
# The following settings, TLS certificates, and keys have been automatically
# generated to configure Elasticsearch security features on 10-03-2022 10:08:43
#
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Enable security features
xpack.security.enabled: true

xpack.security.enrollment.enabled: true

# Enable encryption for HTTP API client connections, such as Kibana, Logstash, and Agents
xpack.security.http.ssl:
  enabled: true
  keystore.path: certs/http.p12

# Enable encryption and mutual authentication between cluster nodes
xpack.security.transport.ssl:
  enabled: true
  verification_mode: certificate
  keystore.path: certs/transport.p12
  truststore.path: certs/transport.p12
# Create a new cluster with the current node only
# Additional nodes can still join the cluster later
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["DESKTOP-0O0S7HQ"]

# Allow HTTP API connections from localhost and local networks
# Connections are encrypted and require user authentication
http.host: [_local_, _site_]

# Allow other nodes to join the cluster from localhost and local networks
# Connections are encrypted and mutually authenticated
#transport.host: [_local_, _site_]

#----------------------- END SECURITY AUTO CONFIGURATION -------------------------
```

I have tried out searching the exceptions online but nothing seems to work. Please help me in figuring this out. Thank you.

Comment: ConnectionClosedException seems to hint at the fac that your Spring Boot application cannot establish a connection to your ES cluster, maybe?

Comment: When I run the app, on cmd window where ES is running I get "received plaintext http traffic on an https channel, closing connection" message. Is this helpful?

Comment: Yes, it looks like you're using ES8, so you can find the answer to your question in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71469707/4604579 (hint: SSL/TLS is on by default in ES8)

Comment: Yes I can access through https but I want the application to run. The application is not running and when I run I get the above exception in eclipse and the plaintext message on the cmd window.

Comment: ...which means the application is accessing ES using http instead of https

Comment: Exactly, how do I change such that it uses https?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ConnectionClosedException seems to hint at the fact that your Spring Boot application cannot establish a connection to your ES cluster.

It looks like you're using ES8, which has SSL/TLS on by default, so you would need to configure your Spring Boot application to use SSL instead.

At 6:00 into the video, `elasticsearch.url` in `application.properties` should be `https://localhost:9200` instead of just `localhost:9200`.

However, as of March 15th 2022, it doesn't seem like [ES 8 is supported by Spring Data ES](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#preface.versions) yet, you might need to revert to the ES 7.15+ release.

Comment: I changed the elasticsearch.url as you said but now I get:  Caused by: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.UncategorizedElasticsearchException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.UnknownHostException: No such host is known (https://localhost:9200); nested exception is ElasticsearchException[java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.UnknownHostException: No such host is known (https://localhost:9200)];

Comment: Can you update your question with your `elasticsearch.yml` configuration?

Comment: I have added my config file.

Comment: Which Spring Boot and Spring Data ES versions do you use?

Comment: spring boot: 2.6.4, spring data ES: 4.3.2

Comment: According to the [version matrix](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#preface.versions), Spring Data ES does not yet support Elasticsearch 8. Also see [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/issues/2108#issuecomment-1067578984), you might need to use an earlier version of ES in the meantime.

Comment: OMG I downloaded ES 7.15.2 and it Worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: Awesome, glad it finally worked out! I think even 7.17.1 would work out

Answer (score 1):

A working spring boot client config with SpringBoot 2.7.1 and Elastic 8.3.3

```
//Below 3 lines are added to make elastic client version 7.17.4 compatible with elastic server version 8x
 HttpHeaders compatibilityHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        compatibilityHeaders.add("Accept", "application/vnd.elasticsearch+json;compatible-with=7");
        compatibilityHeaders.add("Content-Type", "application/vnd.elasticsearch+json;"
                + "compatible-with=7");

        final ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration =
                ClientConfiguration
                        .builder()
                        .connectedTo(<HostName without https://> + ":" + <Port>)
                        .usingSsl()
                        .withBasicAuth(esConnectionDetails.getUsername(), esConnectionDetails.getPassword())
                        .withDefaultHeaders(compatibilityHeaders)    // this variant for imperative code
                        .build();

RestHighLevelClient = RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();
```

Reference:- https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.clients.rest

Answer (score 0):

```
Above will get issue related to SSL certificates. To configure SSL in configuration use the below code.

              @Bean
              @Override
              public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {
              RestHighLevelClient client = null;
              try {
                  final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
                  credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials("elastic", "fdfd65645thtyhu768"));
    
                  SSLContextBuilder sslBuilder = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(null, (x509Certificates, s) -> true);
                  final SSLContext sslContext = sslBuilder.build();
                  client = new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "https"))
                            .setHttpClientConfigCallback(new HttpClientConfigCallback() {
                                 @Override
                                 public HttpAsyncClientBuilder customizeHttpClient(HttpAsyncClientBuilder httpClientBuilder) {
                                      return httpClientBuilder.setSSLContext(sslContext)
                                               .setSSLHostnameVerifier(NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE)
                                               .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
                                 }
                            }).setRequestConfigCallback(new RestClientBuilder.RequestConfigCallback() {
                                 @Override
                                 public RequestConfig.Builder customizeRequestConfig(
                                          RequestConfig.Builder requestConfigBuilder) {
                                      return requestConfigBuilder.setConnectTimeout(5000).setSocketTimeout(120000);
                                 }
                            }));
                   System.out.println("elasticsearch client created");
                  return client;
              } catch (Exception exp) {
                   System.out.println("Exception while client init {}", exp.getMessage());
              }
              return client;
         }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).