# unable to start elasticsearch java application

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I can't start elastic search applicaiton:

```
java 17
elastic 8.5
springboot 2.7.1
```

I get this error

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
> Error creating bean with name 'productRepository' defined in
> io.pratik.elasticsearch.repositories.ProductRepository defined in
> @EnableElasticsearchRepositories declared on
> ElasticsearchClientConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested
> exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
> Failed to instantiate
> [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]:
> Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
> org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.UncategorizedElasticsearchException:
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Connection is closed;
> nested exception is
> ElasticsearchException[java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Connection is closed];
> nested: ExecutionException[org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException:
> Connection is closed]; nested: ConnectionClosedException[Connection is
> closed];

I have my configuration

```java
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "io.pratik.elasticsearch.repositories")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "io.pratik.elasticsearch" })
public class ElasticsearchClientConfig extends AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration {
   @Override
   @Bean
   public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {
      final ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration
            .builder()
            .connectedTo("0.0.0.0:9200")
            .build();
      return RestClients
            .create(clientConfiguration)
            .rest();
   }
}
```

my code

```java
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Product, String> {
    List<Product> findByName(String name);
    
    List<Product> findByNameContaining(String name);
 
    List<Product> findByManufacturerAndCategory(String manufacturer,String category);
}
```

```java
@Service
@Slf4j
public class ProductSearchServiceWithRepo {

   private ProductRepository productRepository;

   @Autowired
   public ProductSearchServiceWithRepo(final ProductRepository productRepository) {
      super();
      this.productRepository = productRepository;
   }

   public void createProductIndexBulk(final List<Product> products) {
      productRepository.saveAll(products);
   }
```

my docker service

```
docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS          PORTS                                            NAMES
0ac7e3cf04f9   elasticsearch:8.5.0   "/bin/tini -- /usr/l…"   11 hours ago   Up 15 minutes   0.0.0.0:9200->9200/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9300->9300/tcp   elasticsearch
```

what I'm missing?

I dont understand the issue and I am expecting working app

Comment: Does this help? [Getting Exceptions while running a Spring boot app with elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71478330/getting-exceptions-while-running-a-spring-boot-app-with-elasticsearch)

Comment: yeah looks like a docker issue indeed, if you can't reach http://127.0.0.1:9200, I would remove the docker image and re-create it

Answer (score 1):

I too faced the same issue and struggled day for this issue when I running local finally I found the fix
we need to get certs generated elastic search and load while connecting to the elastic server from jave

I have used spring boot 2.7.8

```
public class ElasticConfig extends
        AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration {

    private final ElasticsearchProperties elasticsearchProperties;

    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    @Bean
    public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {

        SSLContextBuilder sslBuilder = getSslContextBuilder();

        final ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.builder()
                .connectedTo("localhost:9200")
                .usingSsl()
                .withSocketTimeout(elasticsearchProperties.getSocketTimeout())
                .withClientConfigurer((RestClients.RestClientConfigurationCallback) clientConfigurer -> {
                    try {
                        return clientConfigurer.setSSLContext(sslBuilder.build());
                    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return clientConfigurer;
                })
                .withBasicAuth("default username", "pwd genereated from elastic console")
                .build();

        return RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();
    }

    private SSLContextBuilder getSslContextBuilder() throws CertificateException, IOException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        Path caCertificatePath = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:http_ca.crt").toPath();
        CertificateFactory factory =
                CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        Certificate trustedCa;
        try (InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(caCertificatePath)) {
            trustedCa = factory.generateCertificate(is);
        }
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
        trustStore.load(null, null);
        trustStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", trustedCa);
        return SSLContexts.custom()
                .loadTrustMaterial(trustStore, null);
    }
}
```