# elastic search server not running

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I have downloaded elastic search on my laptop but whenever I go to bin folder of it and do elasticsearch.bat in Windows, some logs appear but the server don't start or show up on the browser.
Logs are pasted below:

```
    warning: ignoring JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151; using bundled JDK
[2022-09-20T21:53:00,089][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [LAPTOP-8VG1D5TB] version[8.4.1], pid[14672], build[zip/2bd229c8e56650b42e40992322a76e7914258f0c/2022-08-26T12:11:43.232597118Z], OS[Windows 10/10.0/amd64], JVM[Oracle Corporation/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/18.0.2/18.0.2+9-61]
[2022-09-20T21:53:00,099][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [LAPTOP-8VG1D5TB] JVM home [G:\elastic stack\elasticsearch-8.4.1\jdk], using bundled JDK [true]
[2022-09-20T21:53:00,100][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [LAPTOP-8VG1D5TB] JVM arguments [-Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60, -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10, -Djava.security.manager=allow, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true, -Djava.locale.providers=SPI,COMPAT, --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED, -XX:+UseG1GC, -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\elasticsearch, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:HeapDumpPath=data, -XX:ErrorFile=logs/hs_err_pid%p.log, -Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=logs/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m, -Xms4053m, -Xmx4053m, -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=2125463552, -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=4m, -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=30, -XX:G1ReservePercent=15, -Des.distribution.type=zip, --module-path=G:\elastic stack\elasticsearch-8.4.1\lib, --add-modules=jdk.net, -Djdk.module.main=org.elasticsearch.server]
[2022-09-20T21:53:13,055][INFO ][c.a.c.i.j.JacksonVersion ] [LAPTOP-8VG1D5TB] Package versions: jackson-annotations=2.13.2, jackson-core=2.13.2, jackson-databind=2.13.2.2, jackson-dataformat-xml=2.13.2, jackson-datatype-jsr310=2.13.2, azure-core=1.27.0, Troubleshooting version conflicts: https://aka.ms/azsdk/java/dependency/troubleshoot
[2022-09-20T21:53:18,911][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [LAPTOP-8VG1D5TB] loaded module [x-pack-voting-only-node]
[2022-09-20T21:53:18,912][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [LAPTOP-8VG1D5TB] loaded module [x-pack-watcher]
[2022-09-20T21:53:18,913][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [LAPTOP-8VG1D5TB] no plugins loaded
[2022-09-20T21:53:29,454][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [LAPTOP-8VG1D5TB] using [1] data paths, mounts [[New Volume (G:)]], net usable_space [246.3gb], net total_space [258.4gb], types [NTFS]
[2022-09-20T21:53:29,455][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [LAPTOP-8VG1D5TB] heap size [3.9gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2022-09-20T21:53:29,737][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [LAPTOP-8VG1D5TB] node name [LAPTOP-8VG1D5TB], node ID [cWMr2jqXSdyI_w8NwYQdjw], cluster name [elasticsearch], roles [ingest, data_cold, data, remote_cluster_client, master, data_warm, data_content, transform, data_hot, ml, data_frozen]
[2022-09-20T21:53:41,627][INFO ][o.e.x.s.Security         ] [LAPTOP-8VG1D5TB] Security is enabled
[2022-09-20T21:53:42,089][INFO ][o.e.x.s.a.s.FileRolesStore] [LAPTOP-8VG1D5TB] parsed [0] roles from file [G:\elastic stack\elasticsearch-8.4.1\config\roles.yml]

[2022-09-20T21:53:43,195][INFO ][o.e.x.m.p.l.CppLogMessageHandler] [LAPTOP-8VG1D5TB] [controller/744] [Main.cc@123] controller (64 bit): Version 8.4.1 (Build c0373714f3bc4b) Copyright (c) 2022 Elasticsearch BV
[2022-09-20T21:53:44,488][INFO ][o.e.t.n.NettyAllocator   ] [LAPTOP-8VG1D5TB] creating NettyAllocator with the following configs: [name=elasticsearch_configured, chunk_size=1mb, suggested_max_allocation_size=1mb, factors={es.unsafe.use_netty_default_chunk_and_page_size=false, g1gc_enabled=true, g1gc_region_size=4mb}]
[2022-09-20T21:53:44,545][INFO ][o.e.i.r.RecoverySettings ] [LAPTOP-8VG1D5TB] using rate limit [40mb] with [default=40mb, read=0b, write=0b, max=0b]
[2022-09-20T21:53:44,668][INFO ][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule    ] [LAPTOP-8VG1D5TB] using discovery type [multi-node] and seed hosts providers [settings]
[2022-09-20T21:53:48,249][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [LAPTOP-8VG1D5TB] initialized
[2022-09-20T21:53:48,251][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [LAPTOP-8VG1D5TB] starting ...
[2022-09-20T21:53:48,313][INFO ][o.e.x.s.c.f.PersistentCache] [LAPTOP-8VG1D5TB] persistent cache index loaded
[2022-09-20T21:53:48,315][INFO ][o.e.x.d.l.DeprecationIndexingComponent] [LAPTOP-8VG1D5TB] deprecation component started
[2022-09-20T21:53:48,698][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [LAPTOP-8VG1D5TB] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9300}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9300}, {[::1]:9300}
[2022-09-20T21:53:50,024][WARN ][o.e.c.c.ClusterBootstrapService] [LAPTOP-8VG1D5TB] this node is locked into cluster UUID [jxCXal6sRFuAT73DX5e-0w] but [cluster.initial_master_nodes] is set to [LAPTOP-8VG1D5TB]; remove this setting to avoid possible data loss caused by subsequent cluster bootstrap attempts
[2022-09-20T21:53:50,370][INFO ][o.e.c.s.MasterService    ] [LAPTOP-8VG1D5TB] elected-as-master ([1] nodes joined)[_FINISH_ELECTION_, {LAPTOP-8VG1D5TB}{cWMr2jqXSdyI_w8NwYQdjw}{S-HMyyEWTgW7OjvE4XtKJg}{LAPTOP-8VG1D5TB}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}{cdfhilmrstw} completing election], term: 2, version: 30, delta: master node changed {previous [], current [{LAPTOP-8VG1D5TB}{cWMr2jqXSdyI_w8NwYQdjw}{S-HMyyEWTgW7OjvE4XtKJg}{LAPTOP-8VG1D5TB}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}{cdfhilmrstw}]}
[2022-09-20T21:53:50,574][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterApplierService] [LAPTOP-8VG1D5TB] master node changed {previous [], current [{LAPTOP-8VG1D5TB}{cWMr2jqXSdyI_w8NwYQdjw}{S-HMyyEWTgW7OjvE4XtKJg}{LAPTOP-8VG1D5TB}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}{cdfhilmrstw}]}, term: 2, version: 30, reason: Publication{term=2, version=30}
[2022-09-20T21:53:50,667][INFO ][o.e.r.s.FileSettingsService] [LAPTOP-8VG1D5TB] starting file settings watcher ...
[2022-09-20T21:53:50,740][INFO ][o.e.r.s.FileSettingsService] [LAPTOP-8VG1D5TB] file settings service up and running [tid=55]
[2022-09-20T21:53:50,854][INFO ][o.e.h.AbstractHttpServerTransport] [LAPTOP-8VG1D5TB] publish_address {192.168.1.6:9200}, bound_addresses {[::]:9200}
[2022-09-20T21:53:50,857][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [LAPTOP-8VG1D5TB] started {LAPTOP-8VG1D5TB}{cWMr2jqXSdyI_w8NwYQdjw}{S-HMyyEWTgW7OjvE4XtKJg}{LAPTOP-8VG1D5TB}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}{cdfhilmrstw}{xpack.installed=true, ml.allocated_processors=4, ml.max_jvm_size=4253024256, ml.machine_memory=8500776960}
[2022-09-20T21:53:51,059][INFO ][o.e.l.LicenseService     ] [LAPTOP-8VG1D5TB] license [b3387b5e-8844-40c0-a4fe-8bb3b74b43d6] mode [basic] - valid
[2022-09-20T21:53:51,062][INFO ][o.e.x.s.a.Realms         ] [LAPTOP-8VG1D5TB] license mode is [basic], currently licensed security realms are [reserved/reserved,file/default_file,native/default_native]
[2022-09-20T21:53:51,071][INFO ][o.e.g.GatewayService     ] [LAPTOP-8VG1D5TB] recovered [2] indices into cluster_state
[2022-09-20T21:53:51,440][ERROR][o.e.i.g.GeoIpDownloader  ] [LAPTOP-8VG1D5TB] exception during geoip databases updateorg.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: not all primary shards of [.geoip_databases] index are active
        at org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip@8.4.1/org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip.GeoIpDownloader.updateDatabases(GeoIpDownloader.java:134)
        at org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip@8.4.1/org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip.GeoIpDownloader.runDownloader(GeoIpDownloader.java:274)
        at org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip@8.4.1/org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip.GeoIpDownloaderTaskExecutor.nodeOperation(GeoIpDownloaderTaskExecutor.java:102)
        at org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip@8.4.1/org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip.GeoIpDownloaderTaskExecutor.nodeOperation(GeoIpDownloaderTaskExecutor.java:48)
        at org.elasticsearch.server@8.4.1/org.elasticsearch.persistent.NodePersistentTasksExecutor$1.doRun(NodePersistentTasksExecutor.java:42)

See logs for more details.

[2022-09-20T21:53:52,678][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService] [LAPTOP-8VG1D5TB] current.health="GREEN" message="Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [GREEN] (reason: [shards started [[.security-7][0]]])." previous.health="RED" reason="shards started [[.security-7][0]]"
[2022-09-20T21:53:53,356][INFO ][o.e.i.g.DatabaseNodeService] [LAPTOP-8VG1D5TB] successfully loaded geoip database file [GeoLite2-Country.mmdb]
[2022-09-20T21:53:53,686][INFO ][o.e.i.g.DatabaseNodeService] [LAPTOP-8VG1D5TB] successfully loaded geoip database file [GeoLite2-ASN.mmdb]
[2022-09-20T21:53:59,679][INFO ][o.e.i.g.DatabaseNodeService] [LAPTOP-8VG1D5TB] successfully loaded geoip database file [GeoLite2-City.mmdb]
[2022-09-20T21:56:09,025][WARN ][o.e.x.c.s.t.n.SecurityNetty4Transport] [LAPTOP-8VG1D5TB] received plaintext traffic on an encrypted channel, closing connection Netty4TcpChannel{localAddress=/127.0.0.1:9300, remoteAddress=/127.0.0.1:63342, profile=default}
```

Can someone tell where the problem lies and how to resolve this?? I tried with all addresses given in log but everytime got no response on the browswer

Comment: This thread should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71470277/4604579

Answer (score 0):

Two pictures are attached.

1. Find the `elasticserach.yml` configuration file. Change the security authentication, switch from true to false to achieve no-secret login access. Change both of these to false.
   [image: Sample_Image_1]
2. Add a new configuration to the file("*ingest.geoip.downloader.enabled: false*").
   [image: Sample_Image_2]