# Elasticsearch - Cannot login, WARN received plaintext http traffic on an https channel

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, logstash

I installed elasticsearch 8.5.3 on my Macbook

I also installed logstash 8.5.3 and in its root directory created file **simple-config.conf** with following content

```json
input {
  file {
    type=>"users-ws-log"
    path=>"/path/to/users-ws.log"
  }
  file {
    type=>"albums-ws-log"
    path=>"/path/to/albums-ws.log"
  }
}

output {
  if [type] == "users-ws-log" {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
      index => "users-ws-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
  } else if [type] == "albums-ws-log" {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
      index => "albums-ws-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Based on my reading, I should now be able to

- run elasticsearch with `/bin/elasticsearch`

, this executed fine and gave me temp 'elastic' user and password

- go to http://localhost:9200/  and ender 'elastic' user and given password

, but this is not working and all browser shows is

**This page isn’t working
localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE**

, and elasticsearch shows in terminal:

**[2022-12-27T15:26:09,914][WARN ][o.e.x.s.t.n.SecurityNetty4HttpServerTransport] [my-MacBook-Pro.local] received plaintext http traffic on an https channel, closing connection Netty4HttpChannel{localAddress=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:9200, remoteAddress=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:55989}**

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71470277/4604579

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

Instead of going to http://localhost:9200/

, go to **https**://localhost:9200/

So, use **https** instead of http and you will be prompted for user credentials and should be able to login.